# SQL Insert into second table values from first table with pk=fk not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my structure of two tables:

**CompanyInfo**

```
Id
Website (Move to CompanyDetail table)
Company
```

**CompanyDetail**

```
Id
CompanyInfoId(FK_PK)
Address
Country
Website (New Field)
```

I added `Website` column to `CompanyDetail` and now need to move all website entries to `CompanyInfo` where the `CompanyInfo.Id = ComanyDetail.CompanyInfoId`

Example data:

**CompanyInfo**

```
1,www.google.com, Google
2,www.yahoo.com, Yahoo
3,www.microsoft.com, Microsoft
```

**CompanyDetail**

```
1,1,adman street, www.google.com
2,1,adman street, www.google.com
3,1,adman street, www.google.com
4,2,yahoo street, www.microsoft.com
```

I am trying this similar query but something is off.

```
insert into CompanyDetail (Website) 
    select Website 
    from CompanyInfo 
    where CompanyInfo.Id = CompanyDetail.ComanyDetailId
```

Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to do an update instead of an insert.

```
UPDATE  cd
SET     Website = c.Website
FROM    CompanyDetail AS cd
        INNER JOIN Company AS c ON c.ID = cd.CompanyDetailID;
```

Comment: If you found it helpful, please mark as answer :-) Thanks